# Dynamic order by is not working on stored procedure mysql

Tags: mysql

I have written a stored procedure in MySQL were how to order by a specific column is dynamic. Users can pass values like 'asc' for ASC and 'desc' for DESC and then I have to order by that value only. I have used CASE for order by. But When I execute the stored procedure it gives me an error.

Here is the stored procedure I have written

```
DELIMITER $$
drop procedure if exists GETLATEST;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE GETLATEST( in `_limit_row` int(10), in `_order_by` varchar(5))
BEGIN 
    set @limit_rows = `_limit_row`;
    set @orderby  = `_order_by`;
    (
        select ac.id as id,"sharepoint" as system_name ,al2.lct_name as lct_name, ac5.content_type_name as content_type_name, ac.createdat as published_date, ac.updatedat as updated_date, ac.createdat as sorting_date, ac.content_title as title, ac.content_downloadlink as downloadlink, ac.content_downloadable as downloadable, ac.content_filetype as file_type, ac.content_image  as image, ac.content_image_small as small_image, ac.content_introtext as intro_text, ac.content_longdesc  as long_description,
        null as thumbnail_image, null as lct_id, null as subtype, null as approved_date, null as title_acadia, null as document_number, null as target_audience, null as expiration_date, null as owner_name, null as major_version, null as minor_version,
        null as name
        from ap_content ac
        inner join ap_lct al2 
        on al2.id = ac.ap_lct_id
        inner join ap_contenttype ac5 
        on ac.ap_contenttype_id = ac5.id 
        where ac.id  in (
        select ac2.id from ap_content ac2 where ac2.createdat in (
                select max(ac3.createdat) from ap_content ac3 where ac3.ap_lct_id in (select al.id from ap_lct al where al.is_active = 1) and ac3.ap_contenttype_id in (select ac4.id from ap_contenttype ac4 where ac4.is_active = 1)  group by ac3.ap_lct_id 
          ) 
        )
    )
    union all 
    (
        
        select vd.document_id as id, "acadia" as system_name ,null as lct_name, null as content_type_name, null as published_date, null as updated_date,vd.approved_dt as sorting_date, null as title, null as downloadlink, null as downloadable, null as file_type,vd.image  as image, vd.image_sml as small_image,null as intro_text, null as long_description,
         vd.thumbnail_image  as thumbnail_image, vd.lct_id  as lct_id, vd.subtype  as subtype, vd.approved_dt  as approved_date, vd.title  as title_acadia, vd.document_number as document_number, vd.target_audience as target_audience, vd.expiration_date as expiration_date, vd.owner_name as owner_name,  vd.major_version_number as major_version, vd.minor_version_number as minor_version,
         vd.name  as name
        from veev_data vd where vd.document_id in (
            select vd2.document_id from veev_data vd2 where vd2.approved_dt in ( select max(vd3.approved_dt) from veev_data vd3 where vd3.lct_id in ( select vba.lct_id from veev_business_area vba where vba.is_active = 1) group by vd3.lct_id ) and vd2.status = 'Approved'
        )
        
    )
    order by sorting_date
    case @orderby 
        when 'asc' then asc
        when 'desc' then desc
    end
     limit `_limit_row`;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here I'm setting the @orderby variable with values passed by the user like 'asc' or 'desc'. Then I'm using CASE for order by like this

```
order by sorting_date
    case @orderby 
            when 'asc' then asc
            when 'desc' then desc
    end
    limit `_limit_row`;
```

When I try to execute this procedure It gives me an error like this:

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'case @orderby when 'asc' then asc when 'desc' then desc end limit `_' at line 32

How to order by a particular order passed in the input parameter of a stored procedure?

Comment: Sorry about that. I have edited my question @DaleK

Comment: ORDER BY expression is a literal, not a parameter. The same with LIMIT expression. Use dynamic SQL (prepared statement).

Comment: @Akina should use case for the entity SQL query

Comment: You may use CASE in ORDER BY, for example, like ```CASE WHEN `_order_by` = 'asc' THEN sorting_date ELSE TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, NOW(), sorting_date) END```. You cannot use CASE in LIMIT.

Comment: My column sorting_date is fixed but I need to pass ASC or DESC to it based on the case @Akina

Comment: You cannot. The only trick (shown above) is to sort by this date when you need ASC and by the timerange till some fixed datetime when you need DESC.